# Pointers vs references examples, which is better in what cases

Tags: c++

I'm beggining my programming learning and currently i'm wondering of difrences between pointers and references in C++. For exapmle we can use pointer to return more then one value from function (because as far as i know `return` can only give us one value) so here is one feature that pointer give us, but probably we can make the same using references.
Now i have questions:

1. What are the most common and easy to undestand cases in which i
   should use pointers and in which i shoud use references?
2. Which are better to use if I have to my program as safe and as fast as possible?

Thank you for all answers! I hope you'll help me learn and undesrtand every aspect of programming in C++ :)

Comment: This question is _primarily opinion-based_, so it's off-topic for [so]. Also https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: A function *can* return more than one value if you just store the values inside a larger object. For example `std::vector<int> f();` could returns millions of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is a variable that holds memory address of another variable. A pointer needs to be dereferenced with * operator to access the memory location it points to.
A reference variable is an alias, that is, another name for an already existing variable. A reference, like a pointer is also implemented by storing the address of an object.
A reference can be thought of as a constant pointer (not to be confused with a pointer to a constant value!) with automatic indirection, i.e the compiler will apply the * operator for you.
Differences :

Reassignment: A pointer can be re-assigned. This property is useful for implementation of data structures like linked list, tree, etc. See the following examples:

```
int x = 5;
int y = 6;
int *p;
p =  &x;
p = &y;
```

On the other hand, a reference cannot be re-assigned, and must be assigned at initialization.

```
int x = 5;
int y = 6;
int &r = x;
```

Comment: Thnak you! Now i get it :)

Comment: Also; a pointer can point to nothing (`nullptr`), a reference cannot.

Comment: @szeejdi - one issue with C++ reference syntax, is you can't tell from the calling code which if any parameters are references and could be modified by the called code. This is more of an issue for larger projects, where the function and/or function prototype may be defined in other files (another source or include file).

Comment: Ok i get it @rcgldr thank you for your time and helping me too! :)

Comment: A pointer can point to anywhere.  A reference refers to an existing item.